# Angular test service is undefined

Tags: angular, testing

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CallsClient, CallVm } from './web-api-client';

import { ConsultationDataService } from './consultation-data.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


describe('ConsultationDataService', () => {
  let service: ConsultationDataService;
  let callsClientSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<CallsClient>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('CallsClient', ['get']);
    spy.get.and.returnValue(of(new CallVm()));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ConsultationDataService,
        { provide: CallsClient, useClass: spy }
      ]
    })

    service = TestBed.inject(ConsultationDataService);
    callsClientSpy = TestBed.inject(CallsClient) as jasmine.SpyObj<CallsClient>;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When my test runs, service is undefined!! What am I doing wrong? ConsultationDataService is only dependent on CallsClient!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `useValue` instead of `useClass` when providing `CallsClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Mauro Aguilar pointed out the the typo! useValue instead of useCase!

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    ConsultationDataService,
    { provide: CallsClient, useValue: spy }
  ]
})
```